# RabbitMq-server required feature flag not enabled! It must be enabled before upgrading RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, feature-flags

I had this issue when i try do install rabbitmq-server following this guide I[nstalling on Debian and Ubuntu](https://rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#server-logs), but when i try to execute systemctl start rabbitmq-server.service or rabbitmq-server this erros occurs

```
2024-01-24 10:43:30.104675-03:00 [error] <0.235.0> Feature flags: `classic_mirrored_queue_version`: required feature flag not enabled! It must be enabled before upgrading RabbitMQ.
2024-01-24 10:43:30.111175-03:00 [error] <0.235.0> Failed to initialize feature flags registry: {disabled_required_feature_flag,
2024-01-24 10:43:30.111175-03:00 [error] <0.235.0>                                               classic_mirrored_queue_version}

BOOT FAILED
2024-01-24 10:43:30.117280-03:00 [error] <0.235.0> 
2024-01-24 10:43:30.117280-03:00 [error] <0.235.0> BOOT FAILED
2024-01-24 10:43:30.117280-03:00 [error] <0.235.0> ===========
2024-01-24 10:43:30.117280-03:00 [error] <0.235.0> Error during startup: {error,failed_to_initialize_feature_flags_registry}
2024-01-24 10:43:30.117280-03:00 [error] <0.235.0> 
===========
Error during startup: {error,failed_to_initialize_feature_flags_registry}

2024-01-24 10:43:31.117853-03:00 [error] <0.234.0>   crasher:
2024-01-24 10:43:31.117853-03:00 [error] <0.234.0>     initial call: application_master:init/4
2024-01-24 10:43:31.117853-03:00 [error] <0.234.0>     pid: <0.234.0>
2024-01-24 10:43:31.117853-03:00 [error] <0.234.0>     registered_name: []
2024-01-24 10:43:31.117853-03:00 [error] <0.234.0>     exception exit: {failed_to_initialize_feature_flags_registry,
2024-01-24 10:43:31.117853-03:00 [error] <0.234.0>                         {rabbit,start,[normal,[]]}}
2024-01-24 10:43:31.117853-03:00 [error] <0.234.0>       in function  application_master:init/4 (application_master.erl, line 142)
2024-01-24 10:43:31.117853-03:00 [error] <0.234.0>     ancestors: [<0.233.0>]
2024-01-24 10:43:31.117853-03:00 [error] <0.234.0>     message_queue_len: 1
2024-01-24 10:43:31.117853-03:00 [error] <0.234.0>     messages: [{'EXIT',<0.235.0>,normal}]
2024-01-24 10:43:31.117853-03:00 [error] <0.234.0>     links: [<0.233.0>,<0.44.0>]
2024-01-24 10:43:31.117853-03:00 [error] <0.234.0>     dictionary: []
2024-01-24 10:43:31.117853-03:00 [error] <0.234.0>     trap_exit: true
2024-01-24 10:43:31.117853-03:00 [error] <0.234.0>     status: running
2024-01-24 10:43:31.117853-03:00 [error] <0.234.0>     heap_size: 233
2024-01-24 10:43:31.117853-03:00 [error] <0.234.0>     stack_size: 28
2024-01-24 10:43:31.117853-03:00 [error] <0.234.0>     reductions: 160
2024-01-24 10:43:31.117853-03:00 [error] <0.234.0>   neighbours:
2024-01-24 10:43:31.117853-03:00 [error] <0.234.0> 
2024-01-24 10:43:31.124017-03:00 [notice] <0.44.0> Application rabbit exited with reason: {failed_to_initialize_feature_flags_registry,{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]}}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ("{application_start_failure,rabbit,{failed_to_initialize_feature_flags_registry,{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]}}}")

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
```

I followed all the steps and made sure that the rabbit and erlang versions are compatible, how i can enable this flags with a can't connect to the server?

I had to try following this guide https://rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#server-logs

Comment: https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2022/07/required-feature-flags-in-rabbitmq-3.11/

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76712557/rabbitmq-enagle-feature-flags-before-run-server